# Angular RXJS need to understand how service works

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can someone please help me to understand this code

Here is a Service
https://github1s.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/HEAD/components/core/config/config.service.ts

and the service method is called from

https://github1s.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/HEAD/components/alert/alert.component.ts

I need to understand what this method `getConfigChangeEventForComponent` in `constructure()` method actually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to put the code in your question :-)

Here's the method:

```
  getConfigChangeEventForComponent(componentName: NzConfigKey): Observable<void> {
    return this.configUpdated$.pipe(
      filter(n => n === componentName),
      mapTo(undefined)
    );
  }
```

From looking at `getConfigChangeEventForComponent`, you can see it is simply filtering the `configUpdated$` stream to emit only when the specified component has changed.  Then, it simply returns `undefined`, which implies that the value isn't useful, but only knowing that the config for a specific `componentName` has changed.

**Essentially, this method returns an observable that emits when the config changes for the specified component.**

If the method simply returned `this.configUpdated$`, then the observable would emit whenever any change was made to any component. However, a couple operators are applied to control when the returned observable emits:

- [`filter()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) is used to only allow emissions where the emitted value equals the provided componentName.
- [`mapTo()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mapto) is used to simply always return `undefined` to subscribers.

---

The `set()` method on the service is what causes `configUpdated$` to emit (by calling `.next()`:

```
  set<T extends NzConfigKey>(componentName: T, value: NzConfig[T]): void {
    this.config[componentName] = { ...this.config[componentName], ...value };
    this.configUpdated$.next(componentName);
  }
```

From searching in `githubs1` editor, I didn't see any references that called the `set()` method, but searching github directly showed various places:

- https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/search?q=service.set

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response, one dot is connected GREAT. This one if you can please help, I did not find any thing in component or service which emits new value. can you please help to find this DOT also.